# script to hide more than 1 TD in Table is not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide a few TDs in a HUGE table.

I tried this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "td:eq( 1 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 2 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 3 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 4 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 5 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 6 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 7 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 9 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 11 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 12 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 14 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 16 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 17 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 19 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 21 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 22 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 24 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 26 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
$( "td:eq( 27 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
});
```

but I cannot hide more than 10 Tds with this, so I came up with the below script. 
I got it from https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/.
Then I tried this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "td:eq( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,11,12,14,16,17,19,21,22,24,26,27 )" ).css( "display", "none" );
});
```

But this does not hide a TD at all. 
I'm Sure I'm making a small mistake on the second script, but I can't find out what.

EDIT:
I've found the issue. I'm also hiding certain TD that contain text. They should be displayed: none instead. 
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: `td:eq( 1,2,3,4,5,6..` is invalid IMHO.. you should be doing `("td:eq(1),td:eq(2),td:eq(3)")`

Comment: "but I cannot hide more than 10 Tds with this" Why not? what happens?

Comment: They aren't hidden somehow...

Comment: Okay, there's just too much ambiguity here. Please create a [mcve] and include it in your question. This must include the HTML of the table (or at least a relevant portion thereof). We're playing guessing games right now.

Comment: I've found the issue. I'm also hiding certain TD that contain text. They should be displayed: none instead. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a class on the `td`s that you want to hide, and then use a jQuery selector on that class to hide them?

```js
$('td.hide').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="hide">1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td class="hide">3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td class="hide">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good suggestion.. But why not just add the class `hide` whose `css` property is `display:none`??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao That works too. Either way, one line of CSS or one line of jQuery. CSS is probably faster, so I agree with you.

Comment: @baswijdenesdotcom If you grab table from external website, it doesn't matter.. you can always take one of the above mentioned suggestions..

Comment: I've found the issue. I'm also hiding certain TD that contain text. They should be displayed: none instead. Sorry for the inconvenience.